# View all file from a list

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I´m working on a project that uses Caliburn micro in wpf C#.

I´m in the process that I want to rewrite my method ReadMediaFile() so it displays all files in a folder in a list.

My method looks lite this:

```
     private void ReadMediaFile()
    {
        string result;
        _movieviewmodel = new MoviesViewModel();

        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/Users/v80770/Desktop/Movies/");

        foreach (var file in filePaths)
        {
            result = Path.GetFileName(file);
            _movieviewmodel.MovieName = result;
        }
        AddItem(_movieviewmodel);
    }
```

When I debug the program all the files show in filePaths but only one shows in my list.

The AddItem is located in a class called TreeViewBase (belongs to caliburn micro I think) and it looks like this:

```
        public void AddItem(T item)
    {
        _dispatcher.SmartInvoke(() => Items.Add(item));
    }
```

I got the movie files viewing in my list but my MediaUri binding in view is bind against a specific path file but I want it to change dependent on what I choose

I tried to edit the binding to this:

```
string test = _movieviewmodel.MovieName;
MediaUri = new Uri(test);
```

But only get a exception *"System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.'"*

[Picture of Uri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cl26.png)

New Uri code:

```
_movieviewmodel.MovieFilePath = @"C:/Users/v80770/Desktop/Movies/";

string test = _movieviewmodel.MovieFilePath;
MediaUri = new Uri(test + _movieviewmodel.MovieName);
```

But it always shows the same movie and my _movieviewmodel.MovieName does not change name dependent which movie I choose, it always is the same movie.

Comment: Put the `AddItem` call inside the `foreach`

Comment: Assuming you want to have one MoviesViewModel instance per file, you need to move `movieviewmodel = new MoviesViewModel();` and `AddItem(_movieviewmodel);` inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks, that it solved now. But my Uri does not work now, see edit question.

Comment: You're trying to create an Uri from a file name only, instead of its full path. Add another property, e.g. MovieFilePath, to your MoviesViewModel class and use that for the Uri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creation of a MoviesViewModel item object and `AddItem(_movieviewmodel);` must be inside foreach, otherwise it would add only the last item:

```
foreach (var file in filePaths)
{
    var movieviewmodel = new MoviesViewModel();
    movieviewmodel.MovieName = Path.GetFileName(file);
    AddItem(movieviewmodel);
}
```

or

```
foreach (var file in filePaths)
{
    AddItem(new MoviesViewModel
    {
        MovieName = Path.GetFileName(file)
    });
}
```